# search ordered values in pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rolling-computation

I have below pandas dataframe

```
col1   col2   col3
1       2     new york
0       5     virginia
1       2     YK
..............
```

I have list of city like

```
 L1 = ['new york', 'virginia']
 L2 = ['virginia','YK']
 L3 = ['YK', 'new york']
 L4 = ['new york', 'YK']
```

I want to serch city in pandas dataframe col3. So that it matches in consecutive rows in same order as in list. Here my list L1 and L2 should only match becuase L1 and L2 has all element that are present in strictly same order in columns without skipping.

```
I searhed a lot and find rolling windows, shift etc. but could not get through.
```

Comment: Why `L2` and `L3` didn't match? How do you store these lists? How many are there? Is it a list of lists?... Sorry if I'm missing something.

Comment: Thats not a major problem, only problem is i want to ensure a set of cities are in order in pandas dataframe

Comment: Yes, `["virginia", "YK"]` is also in order in the frame, right? second and third rows

Comment: yes, sorry, i am editing my question

Comment: Is `["new york", "YK"]` considered a match or it needs to be strictly in consecutive order?

Comment: strict order is must

Answer (score 1):

One way is to join the strings in column `col3` with a sentinel, e.g., `"|"` and then when a list to test comes, join it as well and search:

```
joined_col = "|".join(df.col3)

def is_list_okay(the_list):
    return "|".join(the_list) in joined_col
```

sample run:

```
>>> is_list_okay(L1)
True

>>> is_list_okay(L2)
True

>>> is_list_okay(L3)
False

>>> is_list_okay(L4)
False
```

Comment: there are millions of pattern, also mapping is not possible. I have to search the order of strings